# rspec expect child to receive method when parent method is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

```
class Post
  has_many :comments

  after_update :update_comments

  def update_comments(user)
    comments.where(user: user).each do |comment|
      # binding.pry
      comment.do_something
    end
  end
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post

  def do_something
    'Ok, I will'
    # binding.pry
  end
end
```

This is my issue:

```
RSpec.describe Post do
  describe '#update_comments' do
    let(:post) { create :post }
    let(:comment) { create :comment, post: post }

    it 'triggers comment.do_something'
      comment = post.comments.first
      expect(comment).to receive(:do_something)
      post.update(title: 'new title')
    end
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
(#<Comment id: 1, ..., created_at: "2018-06-15 01:31:33", updated_at: "2018-05-16 02:51:39">).api_update(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

But if I use `binding.pry` in either (or both) def(s), I get the console, so I know it's actually being called.

I compared my `comment` variable in RSpec with `self` in the `Comment` class and they match. I tried using `post.reload` and `comment.reload` in RSpec to make sure the association was solid. Not sure what else I can do.

The fact that it triggers `pry` inside the method I'm saying should be received is so baffling to me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more digging, the issue is that my `comment` variable isn't actually exactly the same instance as the variable that RSpec sees in the loop. They differ by the Rails object ID that is assigned on the fly.

I needed to use a spy or stub the method to avoid this issue.